# PHP code being shown in HTML form text fields

Tags: php, html, forms

I have this code to display PHP value in HTML form text field:

```
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="firstname" maxlength="30" value="<?php echo $firstname;?>"><span class="error"> <?php echo $firstnameErr;?></span>
```

Problem is I see `<?php echo $firstname;?>` being displayed in the text area instead of the actual user-input name or a blank field.

I tried using `<? php echo` and `<?=` and neither work any different, my server supports PHP.

How do I fix this?

Comment: If you're seeing *any* PHP code on the client then that means the web server isn't interpreting the PHP code at all, regardless of whether or not the code is correct.  Either you're using a file type which isn't configured to be interpreted and need to change the file type or change the web server's configuration, or PHP isn't working (or even installed) at all and you may need to re-install or re-configure PHP for your web server.

Comment: did you save your file as `.php` ?

Comment: i think the extension of file not php , check this point firstly

Comment: @palerdot yes, file is saved as plc.phpDavid I have other PHP code in the file that isn't being displayed. I was using a separate php file and using form action="" to call it and that worked perfectly fine. But I need to change it so the php and html are in the same file.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this question... not sure who downvoted, but I have negated you.

Comment: <?= is the same as <?php echo "...  witch means that you should exclude echo incase you're using <?=

Comment: `<form method="post" action="">` that's it? You need to show us your full code. @logicalfox - This question stands at being closed for a few reasons. The most probable cause here is a missing `</form>` tag and unassigned POST variables. You have no submit button, so your question is unclear.

Comment: You may need to use an `isset/!empty` ternary operator or `value="<?php echo $_POST['firstname'];?>"`

Comment: @Fred I read online that `form method="post" action=""` is a perfectly valid way to get the php script to access itself. I was using `<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"> ` but removed it while attempting to fix this problem. I don't think any of the rest of the code impacts the question.

Comment: I didn't say that it wasn't valid, am stating that it seems like you have some missing tags. I don't know what you wish to achieve, but from what I tested using `value="<?php echo $_POST['firstname'];?>"` produced the word I typed in the input box, to stay in the input box. @logicalfox

Comment: full code is not missing </form> tag, I didn't include all the code to try and be short and to the point and save people scrolling through 1000+ lines of my code.

Comment: Ok. Well did you try what I wrote? @logicalfox

Comment: if the variable was undefined it would show not the php code, but the error information inside the text box. i tested the code in the question, and it works fine for me, which leads me to believe it's not the php code, but something with how you're trying to access the file

Comment: yes, sorry fred, stressed out, not trying to b rude. I will update the question with more code, maybe it will make it clearer. My problem specifically is that when I load that page in my browser, the form field of First Name: should be blank, but instead shows `<?php echo $firstname;?>` same for all other fields.

Comment: clearly im not "cool" enough on stackoverflow to b allowed to edit the question -.-
i have:
`if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
              if (empty($_POST["firstname"])) {
                $firstnameErr = "First Name is required";
               }
              else {
                $firstname = test_input($_POST["firstname"]);
               } `
and i declared firstname as a variable along with all the other variables

Comment: @logicalfox check my answer, your code works as is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i believe what is happening is you're opening the file by double clicking rather than "running" the file by navigating to it in your web browser.

i tested your code and it works fine. however, if i just OPEN the file rather than navigating to it via http, then the php code displays inside the text box.

remember, php (and other server side script types like jsp) have to be run, you can't just open them, or drag them into a browser window to test them.

so if, for example, you're using xampp or apache, you would go place the file inside your htdocs folder, open your web browser, and type something like localhost/plc.php

btw, here is the code as i tested it:

```
<?php
$firstname = "bob";
$firstnameErr = "phil";
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="firstname" maxlength="30" value="<?php echo $firstname;?>"><span class="error"> <?php echo $firstnameErr;?></span></form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: YES! :D This is exactly the solution! So having the file on the server and navigating to it correctly are a must it seems. Thank you, and everyone who helped!

Comment: you bet! easy mistake to make when starting out